# How to add an image before a table

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

So I'm using JsPDF + autotables for reports, and I can perfectly add text content to autotables pdf, but my issue is that I need to add an image before the first table, potentially even more images after each table, so how I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the content example?

Comment: This worked. I had to play a bit with the positions, nevertheless it did work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content example in the repo provides a way to do this:

```
doc.setFontSize(18);
doc.text('A story about a person', 14, 22);
doc.setFontSize(11);
doc.setTextColor(100);
var pageWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.width || doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
var text = doc.splitTextToSize(shuffleSentence(faker.lorem.words(55)) + '.', pageWidth - 35, {});
doc.text(text, 14, 30);

var cols = getColumns();
cols.splice(0, 2);
doc.autoTable(cols, getData(40), {startY: 50, showHeader: 'firstPage'});

doc.text(text, 14, doc.autoTable.previous.finalY + 10);
```